# Multiple Constructor calls using WCF Services

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, sqlite, constructor

I'm using WCF Services for a project I'm doing, where the Service will query an SQLite Database and return the desired information (Objects)

The problem I'm having is with Constructors and WCF. Is there a way around having the Service constructor called every single time a client connects to the service?

I've included some testing code so you can see what I'm talking about.

Testing code (Simulation of 20 clients connecting to WCF Service)
http://pastebin.com/sP30zm1w

WCF Service Library
http://pastebin.com/MvPLYKax

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are seeing is called "Per-Call" instancing. This means that the service class is created once per call to the service.

The behavior is controlled by the `InstanceContextMode` config setting in WCF. YOu can change this to:

- Per-Call (service created for every call)
- Per-Session (service created for every session)
- Single (service created once, then held as a singleton)

Here is an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx) that explains some of it.
And [another article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193.aspx).

Comment: I really did hope something like this was causing the issue, thanks!